# Write a raster to an Esri ArcSDE geodatabase using FME

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, convert, fme-form, esri-geodatabase

I would like to write a raster (ECW) to an Esri ArcSDE Geodatabase using FME. I think this should be possible as I have been able to copy and paste the raster layer in ArcGIS from it's original location to the desired database. However, in FME I am getting the error 'cannot write non-area feature to an area feature class".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be using the wrong writer.

You probably have "Esri Geodatabase (ArcSDE Geodb)" and need "Esri Geodatabase (ArcSDE Geodb Raster Dataset)".